# Corrupt USB drive only detected by kernel

Tags: drivers, partitioning, usb, kernel

Windows does not recognize my USB drive. Windows Explorer, Diskpart and other tools have been tried by me. The port is working. Only the device manager detects the drive (And shows a yellow triangle next to it). The drive name is Intenso Ultra Line. Other information such as ID's of the USB drive are in the outputs below.

On Linux, GParted and other tools also do not detect the drive. But the kernel does recognize the drive:

**lsusb -t: USB Drive gets detected. (Port 2):**

> /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
>
> |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
>
> ```
>    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
> ```

**lsusb -v: USB Drive gets detected:**

http://pastebin.com/CUME3g8P

**lsusb: USB Drive gets detected:**

> Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1f75:0917 Innostor Technology Corporation

**lsblk: USB Drive does not get detected.**

- Output not needed -

**Here is my Kernel-Log:**

http://pastebin.com/ppmVSpGB

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried installing [Smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org)?

It's [able to detect](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices) some devices by vendor/manufacturer **1f75** (Innostor Technology Corporation). According with your logs, 1f75 is the manufacturer of your device, hence I would give Smartmontools a try.

**[edit]**: since no GUI application has so far detected your USB device, I am in the hope that by installing and running Smartmontools your device will be detected by it and become visible inside Smartmontools' window, hence making it able for you to identify it's special device file (`/dev/something`) or at least its **serial number** (which is part of its unique **id**).

In order to install Smartmontools' precompiled package in Ubuntu, just run:

```
sudo apt-get install gsmartcontrol
```

...and then run it as root:

```
sudo gsmartcontrol-root
```

After this, plug in your Intenso Ultra Line drive at any USB port and then at the Smartmontools application window hit **Ctrl R** in order to rescan the SMART-capable devices. If your USB drive shows up (as expected), you'll see which special device file should be used in order to try to mount it by hand. E.g. if Smartmontools shows your device at /dev/sdb, then you should be able to mount its first partition (/dev/sdb1) by running a command like this (at the example below I'm assuming that your USB drive's first partition filesystem is VFAT):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/intenso && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/intenso -w -t vfat -o nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,flush,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,dmask=0077,showexec
```

If Smartmontools (gsmartcontrol-root) doesn't show your device's special device file but shows its serial number (e.g. 14122400007141, according to your "Broken USB drive" kernel log), then you can use the command below in order to look for the device's full **id** code:

```
ls -las /dev/disk/by-id | grep -i 14122400007141
```

...which shall return something like this:

```
usb-Intenso_Ultra_Line_14122400007141-0

usb-Intenso_Ultra_Line_14122400007141-0:0-part1
```

...so then you'll be able to mount its first partition by running a command like this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/intenso && sudo mount /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Intenso_Ultra_Line_14122400007141-0\:0-part1 /mnt/intenso -w -t vfat -o nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,flush,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,dmask=0077,showexec
```

If your drive isn't visible not even inside the Smartmontools (`gsmartcontrol-root`) application window, you can create a **udev rule** for your device by adding the following to a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, such as (e.g.) `8-intenso-ultra-line.rules`. Assuming that you have Gedit installed (if not: `sudo apt-get install gedit`), run this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/8-intenso-ultra-line.rules
```

...and then add this to the file:

```
# Intenso Ultra Line USB drive by Innostor Technology Corp.
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="14122400007141", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f75", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0917" SYMLINK+="intenso%n"
```

(the `serial`, `idVendor` and `idProduct` attributes can be confirmed by running the command `sudo lsusb -v | grep -A 5 1f75`)

Now save the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/8-intenso-ultra-line.rules`, exit Gedit and then run the command below so **udev** updates this info and restarts its daemon:

```
sudo udevadm trigger && sudo service udev restart
```

After this, you can see if your device's symlinks (e.g. `intenso1`, for its first partition) are listed in `/dev`:

```
ls /dev
```

If no changes happened, restart your system (`sudo telinit 6`) and then try mounting the USB drive:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/intenso1 && sudo mount /dev/intenso1 /mnt/intenso1 -w -t vfat -o nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,flush,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,dmask=0077,showexec
```

If it works, you can add it to `/etc/fstab` so you don't have to always run it by hand. Just:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

...then append something like this:

```
# Intenso Ultra Line USB drive by Innostor Technology Corp. (first partition):
/dev/intenso1 /media/intenso1 vfat rw,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,flush,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,dmask=0077,showexec 0 0
```

Comment: I have now installed it. But I cannot find any tutorials related to recovery or detection. All I can find is some SMART-Monitoring... Could you provide some commands?

Comment: I edited my answer in order to try to make it more useful. Smartmontools was supposed to help you identify your drive's special device file (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) so you could later mount it by hand. In the worst case scenario, I expect that you can use Smartmontools to confirm your device's serial number and then combine it with your previous **lsusb** output data in order to (i) create a udev rule for setting up a static symlink mountpoint to your USB drive and (ii) use `mount` to mount your drive using such static symlink.

Comment: Mint and Ubuntu were not able to open the application. Now I tried Debian (Live Boot) and the application opened. But I cannot see my drive - now I'll try this on installed Debian 8.2.0. But still thanks!

Comment: Nope. Still nothing detected :(

Comment: You mean only Smartmontools didn't work? Or not even creating an **udev** rule worked? Does `ls -las /dev/disk/by-id` return anything? Because your system kernel detected your device, inside `/dev/disk/by-id` there should be something like `usb-Intenso_Ultra_Line_14122400007141-0` (conventionally, the file name starts with `usb`, has the device's name and serial number, and ends with zero). If at least there's a file for your device inside of `/dev/disk/by-id`, try completely wiping its data with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Intenso_Ultra_Line_14122400007141-0 bs=1M`

Comment: It's possible that your device is actually corrupted: it's detected because the chip id instructions still work, but maybe the filesystem part is damaged. Anyway, another possibility is that your device requires a specific linux kernel module. I looked at http://www.intenso.de/downloads_en.php?kategorie=23&produkt=1342699173 but didn't find any Linux driver: only a Windows driver is available. If you still use Windows, you may try the device driver available there, thus if your device doesn't work in Windows with that driver then the filesystem part of your device is very likely corrupted.

Comment: Nope. I don't see it. So I guess it's corrupt. And the driver does not help - and it's for Windows 98 anyways... But still a big thanks! I will sent my drive to warranty.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope the device's tech support staff can address and solve this issue. Good luck.

Comment: I'm just giving it back and hoping for a replacement from the store (3rd party seller).

Comment: I've tried to proposed solution but I end up with a serial number that is equal to 0. Does this mean that my USB is corrupted ?

Comment: @radouxju I don't get it: smartmontools either reads your USB device's info (and thus shows the special device file and/or serial number of such USB device) or it doesn't read such device's data and thus you won't get any info about serial number. What exactly did you do that caused you to see this serial number equal to 0? I mean: what command or program showed "serial number = 0" to you? Anyway, if your USB device is detected by the Linux kernel, **usbview** will show its data to you: first install **usbview** (`sudo apt-get install usbview -y`) and then run it (`sudo usbview`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. smartmonttools didn't work for me. At this stage, I only managed to read something about my USB key with the lsusb command. I'll try usbview later (I don't have it with me here). Note that the key is not recongized on other computers, so I guess that it is corrupted.